# Indentation of a simple Python program

Tags: python, indentation

```
playerA=input("Please choose one from rock paper and scissors")
playerB=input("Please select one from rock paper and scissors")
if      playerA=rock and playerB=paper:
        print("player B wins")

elif playerA=scissor and playerB=paper:
         print("Player A wins, Congratulations Player A. Do you want to play 
        another game? ")

elif playerA=rock and playerB=rock:
         print("game is draw,  Do you want to play another game")

elif playerA=paper and playerB=paper:
         print("game is draw")

elif playerA=scissor and playerB=scissor:
         print("game is draw")

  elif playerA=paper and playerB=scissor: 
         print("Player B wins, Congratulations Player B. Do you want to play another game?") 

  elif playerA=scissor and playerB=rock:
         print("Player B wins, Congratulations Player B. Do you want to play another game?")

  elif  playerA=rock and playerB= scissor:
         print("Player A wins, Congratulations Player A. Do you want to play another game?")

  elif playerA=paper and playerB=rock:
         print("player A wins, Congratulations Player A. Do you want to play another game?")
```

May I know how I should fix the indentation here, the error I get says that the 
unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

Comment: Ironically, you haven't correctly indented your question to format your code...

Comment: Check you must have mix of tab and space

Comment: BTW, you have to look at basics of python. condition operator is `==` not `=`

Comment: some elif are uncorrectly indented (four last) or print are uncorrectly indented. Generally you have to indent with 4 spaces or tab ekey (configured to do 4 spaces). By the way, you have some condition which doesn't use correct operator ("=" instead of "=="). And you are trying to match variable instead of string 'rock'. There are a lot of mistakes, try to find some basic notion about python, it will be worth it.

Comment: Fixed code formating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the else statement. Like this

> else 
>   only 
>   no statement is required

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing only a space after the 'if' instead of a tab ?

```
    if      playerA==rock and playerB==paper:
```

would become :

```
    if playerA==rock and playerB==paper:
```

Plus, your second last elif has one space in more. Removing it should help too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to un-indent all your code and then use tab to do the indentation properly. You have a mix of tab and spaces, this is where the problem is.

Yoou can also use the `reindent.py` script that you find in the `Tools/scripts/` directory of your Python installation. Change Python (.py) files to use 4-space indents and no hard tab characters. Also trim excess spaces and tabs from ends of lines. Also ensure the last line ends with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Remove blank space before elif after this code..

`elif playerA=paper and playerB=paper:
         print("game is draw")

elif playerA=scissor and playerB=scissor:
         print("game is draw")`